# Sqlalchemy: Retrieve related rows with filters applied

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have two models for mysql database tables as below:

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    datas = relationship('Data', backref='product')
    created_date = Column(Date(), default=date.today())


class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.id'), nullable=False)
    price = Column(Float(2), nullable=False, default=0.0)
    revenue = Column(Float(2), nullable=False, default=0.0)
    profit = Column(Float(2), nullable=False, default=0.0)
    ordered_items = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    profit_margin = Column(Float(2), nullable=False, default=0.0)
    created_date = Column(Date(), default=date.today())
```

Product table have fixed number of rows but its related rows gets created daily i.e. Data table gets new row for each product everyday.

When I run:

```
product = session.query(Product).first()
datas = product.datas
```

I get all the related rows populated in *product.datas* .

What I want to retrieve is datas in *product.datas* that are created not older than one month. Above query provides all the related rows and it should be checked in code(python) if its older than a month before proceeding with other calculations. The matter gets worse each day because of new rows being created. This has reduced performance just within 3 months and will become worse.

I delved into sqlalchemy [relationship loading technique](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html) and more into querying options but could not find a way to do it.

It should be available I think because it uses left outer join to populate related attribute(*datas in this case*) in background.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I doubt if `(2)` is really what you want on `FLOAT`.  Or maybe you need `DECIMAL(2)`?